# Generating leaflet markers with forEach in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, leaflet, meteorite

I am trying to generate a marker for every geotag in a database using Meteor and leaflet package which I've added through Meteorite.

I've been messing around with the following code and nothing seems to work:

```
Geoposts = new Meteor.Collection("geoposts");

Geoposts.insert(
    {"location":
     {"latitude": "40.4417",
     "longitude": "-80.000"},
    "message": "Hi, I am a message."}
);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.sites.rendered = function() {
 // create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
      var map = L.map('map').setView([40.4417, -80.0000], 13);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// add a marker in the given location, attach some popup content to it and open the popup
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'packages/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png',
    shadowUrl: 'packages/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
});

var coordForPin = Geoposts.find({location:{latitude:{}}, longitude:{}});
coordForPin.forEach(function(){
L.marker([coordForPin], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
});
}};

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  })};
```

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The callback argument to [*cursor*.forEach](http://docs.meteor.com/#foreach) should take and use the document as an argument. Also, if your Geoposts collection is not static, consider [observing](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) your cursor to add/remove/change map markers reactively, rather than using `forEach`.